# How to show / hide a list of items with a button based on the number of items (Angular)

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items like:

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="show in data_shows">
        <span class="program_shows_show_day">{{show[2]*1000 | amDateFormat:'ddd D MMM'}}</span>
        <span class="program_shows_show_time">{{show[2]*1000 | amDateFormat:'H:mm'}} - {{show[3]*1000 | amDateFormat:'H:mm'}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

When there are more than 4 items I would like to show only the first 4 items and hide the rest with a button ('Show all').

With jQuery I would just count the items and if they're over 4 items apply a class to the `<ul>`. In Angular it's a bit more difficult- I know ng-repeat produces a $index variable, but I can only use that within the `<li>` items right? So what's the best way to apply a class on the `<ul>` element?

Answer (score 4):

`ngClass` is your best bet:

```
<ul ng-class="{'my-hiding-class': data_shows.length > 4}">
 ...
```

This just says add the class 'my-hiding-class' to the ul when your collection size is greater than 4. Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

**EDIT:**

For the button you'd need to do something like this:

```
<button ng-click="toggleList()"></button>
```

Then in your directive:

```
scope.toggleList = function() {
  scope.showList = !scope.showList;
};
```

Then change your `ngClass` declaration slightly:

```
<ul ng-class="{'my-hiding-class': data_shows.length > 4 && showList}">
```

**Edit 2:**

Using the limitTo filter seems nice, but you might want to wrap it with custom functionality if you decide to go the filter route:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('limitlessFilter', function($filter){
  return function(objects, limit, showAll) {
    if(showAll){
      return objects;
    } else {
      return $filter('limitTo')(objects, limit);
    }
  }
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="show in data_shows | limitlessFilter:4:showAll">
  ...

<button ng-bind="showAll && 'Show Less' || 'Show More'" ng-click="toggleShowAll()"></button>
```

In your controller/directive

```
scope.toggleShowAll = function() {
  scope.showAll = !scope.showAll;
};
```

On a side note, if you want to limit the number of renders your li go through, be sure to use `track by` on your ng-repeat. Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: This works great, thanks! I know also have to add the button that toggles the class (my-hiding-class) on or off. I have this code: `<a href ng-if="data_shows.length > 4" ng-click="showMe = !showMe">See more</a>`. Is there a way to make the `<ul>` element listen to the ng-click command?

Comment: @Mike: How exactly does it only show the first 4 items ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem, I would assume he's setting some CSS properties on the class that he wants to assign to the <ul> to limit the height. Upon seeing your answer, however, @Squrler might want to consider the fact that rendering all <li> elements and hiding them may be inefficient (depending on the size of the list). On a side note, your implementation seems to be a little messy for my taste so I would opt for creating a custom filter to wrap `limitTo`

Comment: @Mike: You are right in that it is inefficient to render all elements just to hide some of them away using CSS. A custom filter won't help here. The proper way is to define a directive for a "limitItems" ul, that add the buttons and handles all the limiting logic. I just wanted to keep it more straight-forward for the OP to more easily get the idea. What do you find "messy" about my implementation though ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem, it's messy in the fact that your logic depends on changing to the limit variable to the length of the array of items... which is a possibly changing value. The solution I have just provided is indifferent to the amount of data within the array and says definitively "Show me all items, or show me the number of items I specify. Nothing between"

Comment: @Mike: Yea, that's true (although I think it is more like a feature): if suddenly more items are loaded, the `Show all` button will automagically get enabled again, but the view won't expand in the user's face :) Of course, in a proper solution one could watch over the items-list and adapt limit accordingly. The main problem with your solution is that it requires fixed height per item (and the number of items cannot be customized by the user) - unless I am missing something.

Comment: Dude, the guy wanted to know how to dynamically bind a class to an element, and that's what I gave him. I also gave him an awesome, reusable custom filter to put on all his elements he might need this for. I didn't come here to talk about the possibility of variable height on items within a given unordered list just because you feel like arguing with strangers on the internet. @Squrler can decide who's more right.

Comment: All good guys. In this specific case I like Mike's answer just a little bit more than ExpertSystems'. Thanks both for your enthusiastic responses and lively banter!

Comment: @Squrler: 1. Somehow I had missed the _"So what's the best way to apply a class on the <ul> element?"_ part. So my answer indeed addressed a different problem than the one asked (although I still like my implementation better). 2. Somehow I also missed @ Mike's last comment: _"just because you feel like arguing with strangers on the internet."_ WOW !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular's **[`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)** filter to originally limit the number of displayed items to 4.

Additonally, you can have 2 buttons (one for showing all items, one for limiting the displayed items to 4) and show/hide them (or disable/enable them) according to the currently displayed items and the total number of items.

E.g.:

```
// VIEW
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:limit">{{item}}</li>
</ul>

<button ng-click="setLimit(4)" ng-disabled="(limit===4)||(items.length<=4)">
    Show few
</button>
<button ng-click="setLimit(0)" ng-disabled="items.length<=limit">
    Show all
</button>

// CONTROLLER
$scope.items = [...];
$scope.limit = 4;
$scope.setLimit = function (lim) {
    $scope.limit = (lim <= 0) ? $scope.items.length : lim;
};
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/8Rr8S/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Only add 4 items to your data_shows collection in your controller. That way you can test the logic, testing the view would be more tricky.

Comment: A hunch really. Testing controllers is easy. I just thought views would be more complex but I guess it's just a case of finding the appropriate dom element and counting the children.

Comment: The view and the controller are tested separately. Testing the controller will be just as easy (instead of verifying that `data_shows.length` equals 4, you'll verify that `showOnly4` equals true or something). Testing the view is fairly straight-forward as well as you already mentioned (just counting number of elements). Your's is viable alternative (and not a bad one under certain assumptions), but not for testability-related reasons. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="show in data_shows | limitTo:4">
    <span class="program_shows_show_day">{{show[2]*1000 | amDateFormat:'ddd D MMM'}}</span>
    <span class="program_shows_show_time">{{show[2]*1000 | amDateFormat:'H:mm'}} - {{show[3]*1000 | amDateFormat:'H:mm'}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<button ng-hide="data_shows.length < 4">Show more</button>
```

You could replace the first "4" with a variable in your scope and modify this value when clicking the button.

But yeah, BenCr's answer sounds better in some ways.